# all Rich text editors runs onChange functions without any change on the component?

Tags: reactjs, rich-text-editor, quill

I tried with several react text editors like Quill, CKEditor, and others, and all reacts in the same way on my app.

I got an app that calls an api to a backend so I set the state:

```
   const [values, setValues] = useState({
            user:{},
            notes: '',
            prescription: '',
     });
```

I make the API CALL

```
function getInfo() {
        //Traer la información de la consulta
        getdataAPI(id).then((response) => {
            if (response.data.error) {
                console.log(response.data.error);
            } else {
                console.log('FROM API TO SET ON VALUES ACT:', response.data);
                setValues({
                    ...values,
                    user: response.data.patient,
                    notes: response.data.notes,
                    prescription: response.data.prescription,
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

The response of the api on the console.log is:

```
{
user: {name: Mike},
notes: '<p>Line One</p><p>Line Two</p>',
prescription: '<p>Line One</p><p>Line Two</p>'
}
```

So I have the handleChange function:

```
const handleQuillChange = (name) => (value) => {
        console.log('Entro a Handle...');
        if (name === 'Prescription') {
            console.log('Entro PRES');
            setValues({ ...values, prescription: value });
        }
        if (name === 'Notes') {
            console.log('Entro a NOTES');
            setValues({ ...values, notes: value });
        }
    };
```

I use the hook useEffect to limit the api get:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getInfo();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, []);
```

I render the two components of quill like that:

```
return(
<Fragment>
    <ReactQuill
          theme='bubble'
          value={values.notes}
          onChange={handleQuillChange('Notes')}
    />
 <ReactQuill
          theme='bubble'
          value={values.prescription}
          onChange={handleQuillChange('Prescription')}
  />
</Fragment>
)
```

The expected result is to have 2 rich text editors with the values from the API. But one of them always starts as blank space...

Debugging I found that the the components on the rich text editors run the `handleChange` function without any change... and that changes the state from the state on the API to the initial state with blank spaces in all the fields exept one of the rich editors...

I change that components (rich text editors) with text area components and works as I expected even with the same functions and values just changing the components...

Somebody can explain me why the componentes trigger the handle change without any handle change? or how to fix the problem I have?